# Calculate a network between two 2 IP address non CIDR

Tags: networking, ipv4, subnet, cidr

I have problem Where I have given two IPv4 address and I have to calculate best possible network between them . For example I have `10.240.204.160` and `10.240.220.160` and I have to find all minimum available subnets between.

Please note that these two IP addresses are not CIDR notation.

The solution which I thought .i.e

1. get the number of host between them (it is 4096 here)
2. find set bit in 4096 which is 12th bit
3. Now create a subnet mask of 20 i.e 255.255.240.0
4. This way I will get subnet masks in between those two IP addresses

Now the question is suppose I got `255.255.240.0` then anding it with start IP it will give network `10.240.192.0/20`  which will serve

`10.240.192.1 to 10.240.207.255` but I started with `10.240.204.160 to 10.240.220.160` hence It would be breaking wrongly

Feels like I will be doing huge mistake If I go with my version of story.

Anyone here please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for pre-made code and stumbled on this thread.  I ended up writing the following in python.  You always have the chance that you will span 2 subnets.  You were just missing the last step here to check and expand by one bit on the netmask if necessary.

```
def calc_inclusive_subnet(ip1, ip2): #accepts 2 IP strings
    #make IP Address objects
    ip1_obj=ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip1)
    ip2_obj=ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip2)
    
    if ip1_obj<=ip2_obj:
        min_ip=ip1_obj
        max_ip=ip2_obj
    else:
        min_ip=ip2_obj
        max_ip=ip1_obj
        
    distance = int(max_ip)-int(min_ip)
    ip_range=0 #increment powers of 2 until you have subnet distance
    while 2**ip_range < distance:
        ip_range += 1
          
    net = ipaddress.IPv4Network(str(min_ip) + '/' +str(32-ip_range), strict=False)
    if max_ip not in net: 
    # i.e. if the distance implies one size network, but IPs span 2
        ip_range+=1
        net = ipaddress.IPv4Network(str(min_ip) + '/' +str(32-ip_range), strict=False)
        
    return net
```

Comment: Thanks, was very usefull!. There's a little error at the "else" of `if ip1_obj<=ip2_obj:`, you are assigning twice `min_ip`, instead of `min_ip`/`max_ip`

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong mask. You should use a `/19` instead of `/20`.

A `/20` offers you 16 subnets. Simple math learns us **192+16 = 208** (192 is the result of 0 + 16 = 16, 16 + 16 = 32, 32 + 16 = 48, etc)

A `/19` offers you 32 subnets --> **192 + 32 = 224**

Keep in mind **224** is the start of the next network. Your `/19` network will have subnets starting from `10.240.192.0/24` to `10.240.223.0/24`.

`10.240.204.160` and `10.240.220.160` belong to the `10.240.192.0/19` network.

Comment: Actually I have to calculate the subnets in between of 10.240.204.160 and 10.240.220.160 . If I will keep /19 then I would be  having a very large range where I doubt that IPs less than 10.240.204.160 may be part of some other network already. So the range is limited cant go outside it while calculating  the subnet

Comment: @Akaks, `10.240.204.160/20` belongs to the network `10.240.192.0/20`, whereas `10.240.220.160/20` belongs to the `10.240.208.0/20` network. So you see, 2 different networks. That's why you'll need the `/19` mask.

Comment: Now I found the exact problem what I have , Here http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=118346  . I am trying to find its answer now , please update if you find any thing

Comment: @Akaks, you never requested anything about programming. You just wanted to know how to calculate the network between 2 addresses (which I provided). If you want an answer on how to do it in Perl I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: Well thanks for the comment , I was looking for any formula or algo to do so  that I write a program

Comment: @Akaks, I'd definitely add that to the question, because you seem to have forgotten the most important part of the question then ;)

Comment: May be I dint explain my problem well , thanks for the response . The question still same as I need to take care that only given host should come in to it . If I took /19 it would be differing from original input which is in between of 10.240.204.160-223.255 . I am sure If you will go though above link you can tell it logically .

Comment: @Akaks, I think you need to Google the basics of IP addressing. A `/19` mask will give you the range `10.240.192.0 to 10.240.223.255` (which includes both IP addresses you provided. A `/20` mask will give you the range `10.240.192.0 to 10.240.207.255` (which only includes the `10.240.204.160` IP).You could have a look [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html)